# JWT Token Security vulnerability and request for possible solution

Tags: api, security, user-interface, jwt, websecurity

I have a question on JWT on the security aspect.
Consider X application using JWT as their security in their Gateway. And this token is valid for 3 mins from origin.

So scenario as follows:

X application login in UI end. Hence the UI call has to go to the gateway first and get the JWT token created. Hence the response sends back to UI. So further requests from UI are going with JWT token to the service layer. This time Gateway validates the token which holds in the header of the requests. And it allows further to the service layer.
This above all process happening in 1st minute of token and so the JWT token exposed in the UI end by simply doing dev tool, we can able to find.

Now anybody who has the API service URL can use this JWT token and access our API Services right? isn't it a security issue. ? or any way to address this issue?

Comment: Why should that be an issue? Why not add more details to the security layer, if you need them (like validating the IP address associated with the token)

Comment: I cant. and it's an open application and all around the globe can access my applications. is JWT suitable here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the assumption that someone has stolen a JWT token from the client.

- Your JWT token should be unique in the sense that it holds information that can only **authenticate** a single user/entity. This means that this token **authorizes** actions that can be done by that single user/entity.
- On top of that you should only allow origins that you trust in your gateway/api this can be done by CORS and CSRF. which will render the token unusable except by your client (UI) origin.

Comment: 1. first user not active on this time the hacker using the JWT token then? it not abo ut single-user 2. its a web application and it can access by anyone from any browser. what CORS and CSRF can stop here?

Comment: CORS and CSRF will prevent the hacker from using tools or their machine or other servers to access your API with that token. as for a hacker to be able to have access to both the browser and the token the last thing I would be worries about for that user is your api

Comment: Another thing you can use IPs in the token to prevent man in the middle attacks